# Index of dataframes in a list

Tags: python, dataframe, list

I have a list of dataframes and want to use their indexes for my operations.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

I0 = pd.DataFrame({'Eng': [11], 
                  'Fr': [10], 
                  'It': [9],
                  'Sp': [11],
                  'Jp': [12]
                  })
I1 = pd.DataFrame({'Eng': [9], 
                  'Fr': [4], 
                  'It': [9],
                  'Sp': [11],
                  'Jp': [15]
                  })
I = [I0, I1]
```

When I do `I.index(I0)` it gives me 0 which is correct but `I.index(I0)` gives me the following error:

[Screenshot of the error when asking for another index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUm5B.png)

Is there any other function or method to have the indexes of the dataframes.

Thank you in advance

1. I switched the dataframes and got the same error
2. I used tuples and sets instead of lists and got the same error
3. I switched the order of the dataframes in the list and got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**:

One of the probably many ways to do this would be to make a dictionary of the dataframes rather than a list. For example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

I0 = pd.DataFrame({'Eng': [11], 
                  'Fr': [10], 
                  'It': [9],
                  'Sp': [11],
                  'Jp': [12]
                  })

I1 = pd.DataFrame({'Eng': [9], 
                  'Fr': [4], 
                  'It': [9],
                  'Sp': [11],
                  'Jp': [15]
                  })

I = {'I0':I0, 'I1':I1}

list(I.keys()).index("I1")
```